# How to avoid duplicates in left table where primary key is not unique in joined table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am having SUM issues when joining 2 tables, whereby the primary key is unique in the left table but can be duplicated in the right table. The scenario I have is that a case_id may have for example a payment of £100 in the left table, which is then broken down at a lower level in to 2 £50 payments in the right table. This is causing the left table payment to be counted twice when joining as the case_id exists twice in the right table.

I have tried a number of different variations of the query but have so far been unsuccessful. I have also searched this website but have been unable to find a scenario that fits mine.

```
select distinct
    t1.[r_code],
    t1.[parent_case_id],
    sum(t1.[total_redress_value]),
    sum(t2.[payment_amount])
from
    [SomeTable1] t1
left join
    [SomeTable2] t2 on t1.[case_id] = t2.[case_id]
group by 
    t1.[r_code], t1.[parent_case_id]
```

Expecting the SUM of total_redress_value & payment_amount to be 100 each, however am finding that SUM of total_redress_value is 200 due to the duplicated case_id row from the join. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this type of hierarchical calculation is a little complicated.  You can pre-aggregation `t2` before `join`ing:

```
select t1.[r_code], t1.[parent_case_id],
       sum(t1.[total_redress_value]),
       sum(t2.[payment_amount])
from [SomeTable1] as t1 left join
     (select t2.case_id, sum(t2.payment_amount) as payment_amount
      from [SomeTable2] as t2
      group by t2.case_id
     ) as t2
     on t1.[case_id] = t2.[case_id]
group by t1.[r_code], t1.[parent_case_id]
```

Note that `select distinct` is almost never needed with `group by`.  And it is certainly not needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Group you right table by the PK of the left.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.[r_code],
       t1.[parent_case_id],
       SUM(t1.[total_redress_value]),
       SUM(t2.[payment_amount])
FROM [SomeTable1] t1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT case_id,
               MIN(payment_amount) AS payment_amount --or sum etc - whatever fits your logic
        FROM [SomeTable2]
        GROUP BY case_id
    ) AS t2
        ON t1.[case_id] = t2.[case_id]
GROUP BY t1.[r_code],
         t1.[parent_case_id];
```

Comment: Thank you this has solved the issue - much appreciated!